# Why is AJAX not sending the correct POST data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

As the person types into the input form, I want it to send POST data to the PHP server and check if their username was not already taken.

The input has a name of `username_signup`, but for some reason the browser [both in chrome and firefox] is sending an input name of `username` (I did use `username` initially when I was coding but I switched it to `username_signup` and saved everything). It's really annoying as I have no idea what's causing it to send a POST input name of `username` rather than the correct `username_signup`.

My javascript:

```
$('body').on('keyup', '#username_signup', function(event) {
        /*
         * Set string variable
         */
        var string = $('#username_signup').val();

        /*
         * Set validations
         */
        $('input').alphanum();
        $('#username_signup').alphanum({
            allowSpace: false,
            maxLength: 32
        });

        /*
         * Set AJAX variable.
         */
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login/ajax_check_username_availability',
            data: {username: string},
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        /*
         * When ajax successfully completed
         */
        request.done(function(data) {
            if (data.status === true)
            {
                $('#signup_presubmit').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#username_check_fail').hide();
                $('#username_check_fail').empty();
                $('#username_check_success').show();
                $('#username_check_success').html(data.username + ' is not taken!');
            }
            else if (data.status === false)
            {
                $('#signup_presubmit').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#username_check_success').hide();
                $('#username_check_success').empty();
                $('#username_check_fail').show();
                $('#username_check_fail').html(data.username + ' has already been taken!');
            }
            else if (data.status === 'nostring')
            {
                $('#signup_presubmit').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#username_check_success').hide();
                $('#username_check_success').empty();
                $('#username_check_fail').show();
                $('#username_check_fail').html('Username needs to be at least 2 character long!');
            }
        });

        /*
         * When ajax fails
         */
        request.fail(function(data) {
            alert('Error! AJAX did not complete successfully');
        });
    });
```

My view:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/signup" method="post" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-horizontal">
    <!-- Username -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input value="<?php echo set_value('username_signup'); ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="username_signup" name="username_signup" placeholder="username">
        <p id="username_check_success" style="color: green; font-size: .7em; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 0em"></p>
        <p id="username_check_fail" style="color: red; font-size: .7em; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 0em"></p>
    </div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">sign up (for real this time)</button>
</form>
```

My controller:

```
function ajax_check_username_availability()
    {
        $data['status'] = true;
        $data['username'] = strtolower($this->input->post('username_signup'));
        if (strlen($data['username']) < 2)
            $data['status'] = 'nostring';
        else
        {
            $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('username' => $data['username']));
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
                $data['status'] = false;
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

So in the end, the browser sends a `$_POST['username']` instead of (logical) `$_POST['username_signup']`

Any idea what's causing this annoyance? (I'm using Codeigniter framwork)

Comment: try your `full url` as post url

Comment: Coz you are using `username` in ajax request

Comment: Oh my gosh. Wow. I can't believe I didn't see that one. I'm so used to sending POST data after submit using the name of the input field as the POST data-name that I overlooked what AJAX was sending. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login/ajax_check_username_availability',
        data: {username: string},
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Because you are sending request data **username** string instead of **username_signup** - change data to:

```
data: {username_signup: string},
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do at the request you use in the parameter "data" the taq "username". If you change this to "username_signup" you get "username_signup" in you php. Like this

```
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login/ajax_check_username_availability',
        data: {username_signup: string},
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple you just make the field id as "username_signup" but you haven't change the code in ajax call please correct that to below code

```
var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login/ajax_check_username_availability',
        data: {username_signup: string},
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

Hope it helps......